# How to use SIFT descriptors in knn algorithm to classify images

Tags: c++, opencv, knn, sift

I have successfully implemented OpenCV's SIFT class as well as KNN seperatly, however now my task is to classify images using both SIFT features and KNN. being that the SIFT features are not images themselves - and just single points of an image how would I use OpenCV's KNearest() with the extracted SIFT features to classify the images?

these are the individual classes being used
SIFT:

```
std::string pathSIFT = "C:path of images";
cv::Ptr<cv::SiftFeatureDetector> detector =
    cv::SiftFeatureDetector::create();
cv::Ptr<cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor> descriptor =
    cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor::create();

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat output;
cv::Mat descriptors;

for (int j = 0; j < images2SIFT.size(); j++) {
    detector->detect(images2SIFT.at(j), keypoints);
    std::string s = std::to_string(j);
    cv::drawKeypoints(images2SIFT.at(j), keypoints, output);
    detector->detectAndCompute(images2SIFT.at(j), Mat(), keypoints, descriptors);

    // Append the descriptors to the matrix
    if (i == 0){
        // If this is the first image, create the matrix
        descriptors.copyTo(descriptors);
    }
    else{
        // Otherwise, append the descriptors to the matrix
        vconcat(descriptors, descriptors, descriptors);
    }
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(pathSIFT + s + ".jpg")) {
        cv::imwrite(pathSIFT + s + ".jpg", output);
    }
    waitKey(200);
}
```

KNN algorithm:

```
Mat samples(data.size(), data[0].rows* data[0].cols, CV_32F);
for (int i = 0; i < samples.rows; i++)
{
    Mat rowData = samples.row(i);
    data[i].reshape(1, 1).convertTo(rowData, CV_32F);
}

Ptr<KNearest> knn = KNearest::create();
knn->setAlgorithmType(KNearest::Types::BRUTE_FORCE);
knn->train(samples, ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

// Classify new image from directory 2
vector<float> predictions;
for (int i = 0; i < dataToTest.size(); i++) {
    Mat img = dataToTest.at(i);
    Mat sample;
    img.reshape(1, 1).convertTo(sample, CV_32F);
    float response = knn->findNearest(sample, 1, noArray());
    predictions.push_back(response);
}
```

Comment: For example, if you have 100 keypoints in your query image and N classes with a random number of keypoints in each sample image of that class. For evety of your query keypoints compute k nearest neighbors among all the class keypoints. Give some score values for hits, like the best neighbor assigns a score of 1.0 for that class, the 2nd best neighbor 0.5, the 3rd 0.25, and so on. Sum up the scores for all the keypoints. The highest scored class then wins

Comment: Another approach could be "bag of visual words" but not sure whether knn is used there.